# Keeping Appium session live while working on browser parallel y

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

Is there a way to keep appium session live while iam. Working on browser sesion parallel

Tried using new command timeout as 300 secs in desired capabilities but didn't work out

My flow : create Appium client, browser session and perform actions and then switch to Appium client to resume my activities